# delete postgres logs when database is running - Get back disk space

Tags: postgresql, logging, service

postgres Log files are saturating the disk and I intend to delete all disks after backing up, should I restart postgres service or can postgres see the new free space after deletion without retsart? If no is there a command that forces postgres to see the nes space size while it is running?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "logs"? WAL or what is collected by `logging collector`?

Comment: postgres log files

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't care how much free space you have.  It just cares if its writes succeed or fail.  It is up to the kernel to decide which of those things happens.  PostgreSQL will notice that its writes have stopped failing as soon as they stop failing.

Comment: "postgres log files "  You are just reiterating your ambiguous statement, without clarifying it,

Answer (score 2):

You can delete PostgreSQL log files at any time. Note, however, that deleting (unlinking) a file does not actually delete it as long as a process still holds it open. So you have to notify PostgreSQL with

```bash
pg_ctl logrotate
```

just like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logfile-maintenance.html) describes.